# Calculate the line integral of F=<x,y,z> and r(t)=<cos(t),sin(t),t>?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

**The question:** Compute the line integral of the vector field $F=\langle x, y, z \rangle$ on the curve $r(t)=\langle \cos(t),\sin(t),t\rangle$ for $0\leq t\leq \pi$

**The answer:** $\frac{\pi^4}{4}$

**My work:**
$$\int_{C}F\cdot T\,\,ds = \int_\alpha^\beta F(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \cdot r'(t) \,\, dt$$
$$F(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = r(t) = \langle \cos(t),\sin(t),t\rangle$$
$$ r'(t) = \langle -\sin(t),\cos(t),1\rangle $$
$$\int_0^\pi (\langle \cos(t),\sin(t),t\rangle\cdot\langle -\sin(t),\cos(t),1\rangle) \,\,dt$$
$$\int_0^\pi (-\sin(t)\cos(t) + \sin(t)\cos(t) + t) \,\,dt$$
$$\int_0^\pi t \,\, dt$$
$$\frac{1}{2}t^2 \,:\,0\to\pi$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$

Where did I mess up? I'm extremely confused on all of this.

Comment: As far as I can tell your work is correct and the answer must be wrong

Comment: Well that's frustrating, but it is a practice problem written by a TA so I guess the answer key isn't free from error. Thanks!